# How do flutter client socket connect to socket server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, flutter, dart

I want to connect my socket server through flutter mobile application, but it's not working.

My server code (Node.js):

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("biri geldşi")
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

My Flutter application code:

```
  import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

  main() {
  IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://192.168.1.102:3000');
  socket.on('connection', (_) {
    print('connect');
    socket.emit('chat message', 'test');
  });
  socket.on('event', (data) => print(data));
  socket.on('disconnect', (_) => print('disconnect'));
  socket.on('fromServer', (_) => print(_));
}
```